# AngularJS: How to obtain the filtered array of ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select like this:

```
<select ng-model="myType"
ng-options="type in types | filter:compatibleTypes">
```

compatibleTypes is defined as a function in $scope by controller:

```
$scope.compatibleTypes = function(item) {
 //Returns true or false
 //depending on another model
}
```

In the controller I need to know the first filtered element (if any) of array 'type'.
Or more precisely, I have to set the value of the model 'myType' with the first element of the filtered list, when it changes.

Comment: so implement `compatibleTypes` as [_filter_](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` is an Angular native filter. That means it can be injected to many places, including your controller:

```
var myController = ['$scope', 'filterFilter', function ($scope, filterFilter) {
    $scope.compatibleTypes = function(item) {
        //Returns true or false
        //depending on another model
    }
    $scope.filteredResults = filterFilter($scope.types, $scope.compatibleTypes);
}];
```

Comment: methinks you have a typo: when call `filterFilter`, `compatibleTypes` instead `$scope.compatibleTypes`

Answer (score 1):

Inject $filter to your controller

```
function myCtrl($scope, $filter)
{
}
```

Then you can just use the filter in your controller and you don't have to use it in your HTML anymore!

```
    $scope.filteredTypes = $filter('filter')(types, $scope.compatibleTypes);
```

In your HTML you can use ng-options="type in filteredTypes"
And in your controller

```
$scope.filteredTypes[0]
```

to get the first one!